# Как сделать рандом с примером ниже только с шансом на выпадение какого либо варианта (JavaScript Jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
var text = ["Текст1", "Текст2", "Текст3", "Текст4"]; //и т.д.
  rand = text[Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length)];
  
  if(rand=="Текст1"){
    alert('1');
  };
```

Comment: [1,1,2,3] => 1=50% и 2,3=25%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно вот так.

```js
const text = [
{
  value: "Текст1",
  chanceValue: 50,
},
{
  value: "Текст2",
  chanceValue: 80,
},
{
  value: "Текст3",
  chanceValue: 97,
},
{
  value: "Текст4",
  chanceValue: 100,
}
];

random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  
console.log(random, text.find((el) => (el.chanceValue > random)).value);
```

Comment: Надо было в относительных значениях, предварительно их сложить `cv4 += cv3 += cv2 += cv1` и вставить в `Math.random() * cv4`

Comment: Да, конечно, можно было и так. Я просто привел пример как это можно сделать для понимания.